# How to change position of the app title in .NET MAUI?

Tags: maui

I want to change the position of title to the middle or right side of the screen. I used the following code:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="CostManagement.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CostManagement"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Main Page"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

How can I change its position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be customized by setting the `Shell.FlyoutContent` and use the `CollectionView` to define the appearance of the menu item like the title as you said. You can refer to the **code sample** below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="CostManagement.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CostManagement"
    FlyoutBackgroundColor="LightGray"
    FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    FlyoutWidth="400"
    FlyoutHeight="400">



   <Shell.FlyoutContent>
        <CollectionView BindingContext="{x:Reference shell}" ItemsSource="{Binding FlyoutItems}" IsGrouped="True">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="40,*" Padding="10">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"></Image>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"  TextColor="Black"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Shell.FlyoutContent>



</Shell>
```